# Unable to get java annotation on kotlin method using reflection

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, annotations

I declare a java annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
public @interface JavaAnnotation{}
```

I use this java annotation in kotlin interface

Problem.kt

```
interface IMyClass {
        @JavaAnnotation
        fun method() {}
    }

class MyClass : IMyClass{
    override fun method() {}
}

class Problem {
    @Test
    internal fun shouldFindAnnotationFromParentInterface() {
        val myClass = MyClass()
        Assertions.assertTrue(myClass::class.declaredFunctions.find { it.name == "method" }!!.annotations.isEmpty().not())
    }
}
```

I see that java annotation uses @Inherited.
I want to find the java annotation on the Kotlin MyClass::method.
I get an empty array.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: From the Javadoc for @Inherited: “Note that this meta-annotation interface has no use effect if the annotated interface is used to annotate anything other than a class.”  For what you’re trying to do you’re pretty much stuck with using reflection to figure out which method on the superclass your method is overriding.  You might find Spring’s AnnotationUtils helpful (at least as a reference if you’re not actually using Spring).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.java

Comment: Thanks!!! Great you have an eye for the detail. But I had in general a problem finding java annotation from kotlin. For example if I move  @JavaAnnotation directly in MyClass. I will update the question. I will check AnnotationUtils thanks for that also.